# Is it right to pass a JPanel as a parameter to other classes?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jpanel

I'm sure it's not, but I am experiencing headaches thinking of alternative ways. I have a videogame panel with a background and a character-thread in it. The character keeps changing his position on a 100ms basis and I want to show on screen each step he does. I can easily do it passing the gamePanel to the character as a parameter, but I feel dirty inside when I do it since I know that's the wrong way. 
Any help?

Comment: The way I would do it depends on the following. A JPanel is a container, it is logical that it has knowledge of what it contains. A game-character is an entity that does not need to know how he is painted. I would pass the character to the JPanel and not the other way around.

Comment: The question is, do you really need to all the information that the panel provides?

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong per se with passing the JPanel as a parameter to a method since it's an object like any other, but I do worry about how you're drawing on the JPanel with this. You're not calling `getGraphics()` are you? I hope not.

---

**Edit**
You state/I reply:

> The fact is that I was trying different solutions and now I don't have the version of the code in which I was using JPanel as a reference.

So it's a non-issue then?

> Anyway, in that version everything was fine. I was just worried since in an hypothetical situation with more threads, it wouldn't sound so safe to me to have a shared JPanel for all. Hence the main question.

Threading is almost never an issue so long as you take care to make any and all Swing calls on the Swing event thread, and call all long-running code on a background thread. I don't see how this relates to your original question though about passing the JPanel in as a parameter.

If you still have a question, you will want to clarify it further as you're still talking about murky mumbo-jumbo that we have no access to.

Comment: No, I'm not. I'm just repainting over and over the Image I have, changing the position stored in the character class.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm still not sure what you're doing. Again, passing a JPanel reference is no big deal. What you do with it though can matter. Consider showing a little code and clarifying your question for us. For instance, just what is bothering you about your code?

Comment: The fact is that I was trying different solutions and now I don't have the version of the code in which I was using JPanel as a reference. Anyway, in that version everything was fine. I was just worried since in an hypothetical situation with more threads, it wouldn't sound so safe to me to have a shared JPanel for all. Hence the main question.

Answer (score 1):

JPanel is just a class. You can pass object of any class as a parameter to the method. If you want to pass it to the method in another class, you have to be carefully about access to this another class. But just passing object of JPanel is completely fine